# Need help in Adapter class

Tags: android

I have enclosed my code below my adapter class is not opening neither Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: adapter") is printing can anyone help me why this is happening because I am having in this , I have parsed my response which is printing in the log but the adapater is not working

```
private void hitIniialUrl(String url){
    //        progressDialog.show();
            Log.e(TAG, "hitInitialUrl: " + url );
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url , new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse==== : " + response);

    //                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String statusCode = jsonObject.getString("statusCode");
                        if (statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:---- " + jsonObject.toString());

                            JSONArray dataobject = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("data"));


                            if (dataobject.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataobject.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject dataObejct = dataobject.getJSONObject(i);
                                    try {
                                        BookingHistoryData bookingHistoryData = parseBookingConfirmation(dataObejct);
                                        BookingHistoryAdapter adapter = new BookingHistoryAdapter(BookingHistoryActivity.this, bookingHistoryparsedata.data );
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:   " + bookingHistoryparsedata.data);
                                        ll_booking_results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ll_booking_results.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: adapter");
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:   " + BookingHistoryData.tripChart.size());
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.toString());
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception: " + e.getMessage() );
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString() );

                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+ StaticFields.token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);

     }
```

Comment: You should do the job on UI thread

Comment: show me your code of init view  "ll_booking_results" .

Comment: please show the proper code so understand the issue